# mvn - is not recognized as an internal or external command in Windows 11

Tags: windows, maven, maven-3, windows-11

I have downloaded binary mvn file, extracted it and added the MAVEN_HOME system variable and  %MAVEN_HOME%\bin to path.
https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.6/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.zip

I have tried multiple different directories, restarted PC multiple times and also ran cmd prmpt in administrator mode to eliminate any odds against me.

[image]

Update:
I don't see the .cmd files after extraction. Files are present before extraction. Hidden files are enabled and when I create a .cmd file manually from mvn file, it still doesn't work.
[image]

Note: I have installed maven atleast in 10 other machines in the past. But never stuck as badly.

Comment: First it's only neccessary to add the path to `..\apache-maven-3.8.6\bin` to the `PATH` nothing else is needed. No `MAVEN_HOME` of course you have to add `JAVA_HOME` ...

Comment: What happens when you do `cd %MAVEN_HOME%` and `dir`?

Comment: Yes. I've tested this without initially setting MAVEN_HOME as well. I didn't want any stone unturned. If you observe the path, It has the maven binary directory with bin available yet the mvn command isn't working :/

Comment: @SiKing it lists me bin, boot, conf etc., i.e., the directory structure from the binary zip I downloaded
` Directory of C:\apache-maven-3.8.6

20-07-2022  19:48    <DIR>          .
20-07-2022  19:48    <DIR>          bin
20-07-2022  19:48    <DIR>          boot
20-07-2022  19:48    <DIR>          conf
20-07-2022  19:48    <DIR>          lib
06-06-2022  16:16            17,568 LICENSE
06-06-2022  16:16             5,141 NOTICE
06-06-2022  16:16             2,612 README.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself.
Using the winRAR to extract the downloaded bin.zip file caused the problem.
When accessed directly through winrar, the .cmd files (.bat in older version of maven) were present.
[image]
But after extracting to a folder, the files are missing.
[image]

**Root Cause:**
For security reasons, WinRAR is omitting .cmd and .bat files from extraction list by default.
[image]

Using the default "Extract All.." option from right click menu resolved this.

Comment: Consider using 7-zip.

Comment: I was stuck in the same problem, and the cause was that I was pointing to the archived file( the icon of an archived file in windows 11 looks too much closer to the icon of a simple folder :D ) Thanks anyway, your answer helped me a lot